# Is this really a JUnit report file? Jenkins error with .Json file

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, serenity-bdd

I am trying to execute my serenity cucumber project through Jenkins, 
After execution serenity cucumber produces both *.xml and *.json file. *.xml files don't have gherkin steps under `\target\site\serenity`. JSON file has all gherkin steps. so I thought to  Parse JUnit test results from testing tools in *. JSON format. But after execution,

I have tried to solve this issue with the below plugin by adding it in a runner class. 
`plugin = { "pretty", "junit:target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.json" }` but  I am not able to solve my issue because it's also producing the result in an XML format under *.json file

I am getting below exception after executing my project through jenkins.

```
[qTest] [INFO] Scan with test result location: /target/site/serenity/*.json
[qTest] [ERROR] Failed to read C:\Users\User\.jenkins\workspace\Myproject\target\site\serenity\78156e8cbe07da438639ea79f1389f1ecff88192ee674e22f279196716110f2f.json
Is this really a JUnit report file? 
[qTest] [WARN] No JUnit test result found.
[qTest] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished: FAILURE 

I want to send my JSON result using Junit to a third-party tool.
```

Answer (score 1):

Junit 4 (which is what Serenity uses) produces XML reports, not JSON. All the files in the format `SERENIY-JUNIT*.xml` are the Serenity test results recorded as Junit XML report (the clue is in the name). Jenkins will not be able to read JUnit results from JSON files because (a) Junit 4 does not produce JSON reports, and (b) these are not JUnit reports.